# Question: Authentication using SQL Membership Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlmembershipprovider

I have checked the following article on how to use the [sqlMembershipProvider](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/creating-user-accounts-cs). My question, is this the way most of the asp.net applications authentication schemes implemented.

Is there any other method, any references will be quite helpful for me.

Edit1:
My intention is to know the other possible ways, I can authenticate a user against a standard database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Most" is unfortunately hard to quantify.

MSFT has made it easy to setup an ASP.NET application using SqlMembershipProvider for an out-of-the-box setup, making it super easy to get authentication against a SQL db working.

That said, I rolled my own, because I didn't need much of what the built-in stuff was doing.

The way I did it was to write my own membership provider class, and use the web.config to specify that my customprovider was the default membership provider.

For ASP, there are other ways of doing authentication, such as using NTLM (basically creating windows users for each web user, and using Windows built in authentication).

Short answer: If you can make use of SqlMembershipProvider, and it does all that you need, then I recommend using it.

Comment: My intention is to know the other possible ways, I can authenticate a user against a standard database.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon @Alan (+1) makes good points.

On a simple level if the (trusted) framework you are using offers you a solution that needs configuring rather than coding and it covers your needs unless there is a compelling case against it then it is probably a good solution.

You wouldn't write a new textbox control in asp.net, or a new fadeOut method for jQuery - you would use the provided solution.

I've rolled-my-own in this area and used all kinds of plug-ins and third-parties over the years.  But in the project I'm currently working on we needed user authentication on Tuesday of last week and with SqlMembershipProvider the security module was complete by Wednesday.  That's good enough for me!